# Post moved to server fault incorrectly?

Tags: discussion

https://serverfault.com/questions/584605/dhcp-troubleshooting-client-timeouts/584634#584634

This post was moved to server fault, but the issue was definitely in the switch config.  This issue occurs *very* commonly with Cisco devices and DHCP/PXE.

Does this really not belong on networkengineering?

Comment: You've assumed that things must be *either* on-topic for SF *or* NE.  It's possible that questions are on-topic for both sites... indeed, it took me about 20 seconds to find a [similar problem](http://serverfault.com/questions/507365/) on [SF].   While we might have been able to answer it, consider that we get a fair amount of "please debug my server / computer" questions, and honestly this looked like yet another one of them when I migrated.  The safest thing is migrating to [sf], because both networking & servers are on-topic

Answer (score 1):

I think it's in the right place over on Server Fault.

The root cause is the *interaction* between two features (DHCP and loop-detection/portfast-feature.) Troubleshooting and figuring out what was wrong required much more "server" knowledge than "net eng" knowledge.

Most importantly: SF answered it immediately, and the OP has their solution.